# How to create table without any schema in postgres

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

In postgres is it possible to create a tables which does not comes under any schema? By default If I create a table it comes under
"public" schema. So Is there any way to create a table which does not comes under any schema.

Comment: AFAIK, **no** default schema will be `public`,OTOH you  can create a custom schema .like this - http://hastebin.com/ugokovamiz.sql

Comment: A table is  *always* stored in a schema, you can not have one without a schema.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So, each and every tables must have a schema. Is it right?

Comment: @mrg Just curious to know, why you need this requirement ??

Comment: @wingedpanther Just for clarification